# How can I defer parsing of (a.k.a. dynamically load) the tinyMCE wysiwyg text editor javascript file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, tinymce

I know how to [defer parsing of javascript files](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/mobile#DeferParsingJS). That's easy.

What's not so easy is dealing with the various otherfiles tinyMCE calls after the initial javascript file. Mainly because tinyMCE silently fails I suspect.

If I load the file in via a regular html script tag, it works fine. But if I try to do something like this:

```
var my_local_tinymce_js_file = "http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js";

$.when($.getScript(var my_local_tinymce_js_file)).
done(function(script, textStatus) {

    alert("download of tiny_mce succeeded!");
    setTimeout("setup_tinymce();", 7500);

})
.fail() {

    alert("download of tiny_mce failed!");

});
```

I can always see the text alert "download of tiny_mce succeeded!", and I can print out the script variable in an alert box as well to prove that **it did indeed download the script.**

I have even gone as far as calling setup_tinymce 7.5 seconds in the future, to allow for all of the other javascript and css files to load (which I do not believe are loading).

The setup_tinymce function looks like this:

```
function setup_tinymce() {

            tinyMCE.baseURL = 'http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/';
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "textareas", 
                theme : "advanced", 
                schema: "html5", 
                plugins : "emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview", 
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect", 
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,|,image,|,advhr,|,removeformat", 
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "", 
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top", 
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left", 
                theme_advanced_resizing : true
            });
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'comment_text');

}
```

This is why I am trying to dynamically load the file... https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fwww.tinymce.com_2Ftryit_2Ffull.php&mobile=false&rule=DeferParsingJavaScript

It is rather large, and would speed up my page rendering speed considerably if I could dynamically load it.

**EDIT:** I have even tried some jQuery code like this:

```
$.when(
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/langs/en.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/emotions/editor_plugin.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/editor_template.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/editor_plugin.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/advhr/editor_plugin.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/insertdatetime/editor_plugin.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/preview/editor_plugin.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/inc/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js")
    ).then(


        $(function() {

            //initialize tinyMCE here

        })

    );
```

With no luck. That script loads all of the appropriate JavaScript files (that are loaded when I load the script from the head tag) and then initializes tinymce but does not work. No errors are thrown.

Here are some old forum threads mentioning dynamic loading on the tinymce forum... All of which contain bits and pieces of old code, but no complete examples :S

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=23286

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=2290

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=17467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load tinymce like this might be impossible because the browser does not know how to get all the other needed tinymce files (in case you find a solution (what i do not think you will) let me know - this is of interest to me).

If your aim is to speed up your page with tinymce you may also use the tinymce compressor (see the developer download). This may save up to 1-2 seconds initially.

Comment: I did not know about the compressor version. That's interesting, but even in all of their examples... they load the script directly in the head tag of the page. I think the answer will have something to do with re-initializing the script (faking a page load) but I am not sure.

Comment: examples are usually made as easy as possible for the user to understand - guess thats why there are almost none with the compressor version. i do not know which script langugae you are using, but there are several server side scripts top be used with the tinymce compressor